# How to find key from an object in a map?

Tags: java

Basically, I've the following code:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "test");
map.put(2, "test2");
// I can get the string using this:
String str = map.get("test2");
// but how do I get the index ('key') of "test2"?
```

The code is pretty much self explanatory. How do I get the '2'? Is it essential to use a loop?

Comment: The values of a map are not distinct, which means you can get multiple values matching more keys, therefore you are looking for a `List<Integer>` of keys.

    List<Integer> keys = map.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> "Test2".equals(e.getValue()))
  .map(Entry::getKey)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to using a loop, you can use `Stream`s to locate the key matching a given value:

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream() // build a Stream<Map.Entry<Integer,String> of all the map entries
   .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals("test2")) // locate entries having the required value
   .map(Map.Entry::getKey) // map to the corresponding key
   .findFirst() // get the first match (there may be multiple matches)
   .orElse(null); // default value in case of no match
```

Comment: You could use .keySet() instead of .entrySet() and .map(Map.Entry::getKey)

Comment: @Glavatar if I use `keySet()` I have to call `map.get()` is order to check that the value matches the required value.

Comment: @glavatar but if he uses keySet, you'd only have the keys. But you need to work on the entries, because the entry's value is what to search by ("test2") and the key is what should be determined

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the map's entry and check for the `key`  against matching `value`.

```
    int key = 0;
    for(Entry<Integer, String> entry:map.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue().equals("test2")) {
            key=entry.getKey();
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(key);

    // Using stream
    Optional<Entry<Integer, String>> element = map.entrySet().stream().filter(elem->elem.getValue().equals("test2")).findFirst();
    if(element.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(element.get().getKey());
    }
```